# Destroying/unloading video object HTML5 on ios

Tags: ios, html, video, memory-leaks

I'm loading up multiple videos into one video object inside a webview of an ios app. After viewing a couple of videos, the app would crash, assuming from memory leaking.  I'm looking for a way to properly dump the stream or destroy the previous video when video is paused and closed, or before loading up a new one.  Any help would be much appreciated:

```
<video class="videoPlayer" preload="auto" controls="controls">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

function LoadNewVideo() {
    video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    video.src = "assets/vids/vid" + vidSelect + ".mp4";
    video.load(); // need this for the new video to load
    video.play();
}

function StopVideo() {
    video.pause();
    // kill current video here
    // i've tried the following codes but didn't work
    video.src = '';
    video.load();
}
```